# How to initialize a LinkedList head to None(as done in C++)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

How to initialize head in this implementation of *LinkedList* in python?
I know a Node class can be defined that will make things easier.But I am trying to do in this way(like in C++).

```py
class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self,val=None,next=None):
       self.val = val
       self.next = next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have this one class, then it actually serves as a `Node` class, and you lack the container class that would have the `head` member.

This has as consequence that the program will have to manage the `head` itself. The variable that will be used to reference a linked list could be that `head` variable, but that also means an empty list will be represented by `None`.

For instance:

```
head = None  # Empty list
head = LinkedList(1, head)  # Add the first node to it
head = LinkedList(2, head)  # Prepend the second node to it
head = LinkedList(3, head)  # Prepend the third node to it.

# Print the values in the list:
node = head
while node:
    print(node.val, end=" ")
    node = node.next
print()
```

Output will be:

```
3 2 1
```

Comment: I got it. But suppose i defined a method to find the length of the list then how to handle the situation when list is empty(i.e., head = None) because we can't 'head.length()' as it will throw error ' 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'length' '. Once a node is created then it will work fine but what about this ' head = None' case.

Comment: That is indeed the downside: you don't have a container class, and so you must write functions (detached from a class), that you can call as `getlength(head)`. Once you have many functions like that, it becomes natural to group them as methods of a class, which will have the `head` member. It is quite simple: without that container class, you will have similar functionality implemented in the global (or less local) scope.